# How to typset this field extension diagram

Tags: diagrams

I don't want to use the tikz. Is there some way to typeset this field extension diagram.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you don't want a higher level package, but here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\ext}[1]{% a one shot command for this display
  \hphantom{\scriptstyle#1}\bigg|{\scriptstyle#1}%
}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
L \\
\ext{e} \\
L^{T\vphantom{\big|}} \\
\ext{f} \\
L^{D\vphantom{\big|}} \\
\ext{g} \\
K
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]